# gradle error in expo while making .apk file?

Tags: android, error-handling, expo, error-logging, error-log

I am getting error while making .apk file using expo from react native code project in windows 10.
I made this project as freelancing work.
please help me to solve this git error.
here I attach a pic of error for your reference.
I hope community people give me relevant solution as quick as possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnvIn.png)

I try to solve this error using chatgpt but somehow chatgpt can not give proper solution of this error